# How can I apply a patch to a git subtree merge?

Tags: git, merge, patch, subtree

I added a subproject to a git repository by doing a subtree merge. I now need to apply a patch to the subproject, but running "git apply -v patch_name.patch" returns nothing. There's no error message and none of the files get changed either.

I've tried cloning the subproject separately (ie, into a subdirectory /tmp) and comparing that to what's in the subproject directory under the main project; the directories are the same.

When I run the patch against the clone under /tmp, it applies as expected. It seems that the problem is related to the fact that the subproject directory is the result of a subtree merge.

I guess I could patch the files under the fresh clone and then copy them over what's in the subproject directory under my main project. It seems like I shouldn't have to do that. Is there a better way around this?

Comment: did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the `git apply` manual:

> If the patch contains any changes to submodules then git apply treats
>   these changes as follows.
>
> If --index is specified (explicitly or implicitly), then the submodule commits must match the index exactly for the patch to apply.
>   If any of the submodules are checked-out, then these
>   check-outs are completely ignored, i.e., they are not required to be up-to-date or clean and they are not updated.
>
> If --index is not specified, then the submodule commits in the patch are ignored and only the absence or presence of the
>   corresponding subdirectory is checked and (if possible) updated.

In other words, you must provide `--index` for `git apply` to pay attention to submodules.

If you want to "force through" the changes, you might consider using the normal `patch` command, although it won't get permissions changes and the like, or using a `git checkout rev /path/to/dir` on the subtree (or the manual copy you suggest).